# How to search Google Image's "search by image" using a copied image?

Tags: google-chrome, images, search, google-search

Once I copied an edited image from paint.NET and I wanted to search the image on Google. However, I only found a "Paste image URL" and "Upload an image". However, I didn't have an image URL and I didn't want to save the image. Is there any way for me to search by image?

Thanks.

Comment: Drag the image into the "Upload an Image" box. Or try saving it.

Comment: Yes but is there any other way?

Comment: What other way would you imagine there could be? Either you point at an image already online, or you hand it an image. Mind reading is still work in progress ;)

Comment: Well that's why I'm asking...